# Open new powershell window in python

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I am running a python script from powershell.

I'd like to open another powershell window from this python script so that the script can interact with this new powershell window.

```
subprocess.call('C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe', shell=True)
```

is not openning a new window.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add start befor c:\\ like this: subprocess.call('start C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe', shell=True)

Comment: create a ps1 file and add it as an argument while running powershell. ```subprocess.call('start C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -File your_ps1_file_path', shell=True)``` I dont think you can get input from powershell and use python to process it natively.

Comment: Thanks, this opens a new window as desired. But how can I interact with that window from the python script? I am now using subprocess.Popen and p.stdin.write, but this doesn't work